# Should I Use sqlite or NTFS for picture storage

Tags: database, sqlite, ntfs

My scenario is situation dependent. I am writing a music library organizer/player that will be similar to iTunes, Windows Media Player, and Winamp. I already have all of the ID3 tag code working and now I am ready for the database. To my discovery it is much faster to read a database, check the MD5 hash of a file and compare it to the stored one, and update the database if the song changed, than it is to just read directly from each song's ID3 tags on load. So that being said I just got a sqlite database up and running.

Now I am not sure if I should store the album art in the database or on the file system. I have code that automatically re-sizes the album art to 300x300 pixels so the file size for all of the pictures is usually around 15-30 KB in size. This has been true for normal sized images and 14.8 MB sized images. So on average there would be 22.5 KB sized pictures that I need to store.

Here is the situational dependent piece; I need the decision to be efficient with a music library of 100 songs as well as 20,000 songs. Assuming all of the songs had album art, which method would be better: sqlite database or NTFS file system using subdirectories for quicker load time

Comment: Ok another thing to consider is read time. I will only be reading picture at a time. Would it be better to read the image from a database or from a NTFS file system? Would it make a difference if there was 5,000 images versus 5 images when making the choice of database of file system

Answer (score 0):

In general, databases aren't that great at storing BLOBs but you're already reducing the size of the BLOBs considerably so that makes it less of a problem.

Also, keep in mind that storing a blob per song might be a complete waste of space as you're most likely in a situation where several songs share the same blob.

Due to the small size of the images, I would store them in the database and also adjust the schema to ensure you're not storing multiple blobs with the same image in them. This also makes it much easier to ensure consistent data as you don't have part of the data in one place (the database) and some other data on the file system where the user can accidentally delete it.

Once you're talking considerably bigger blobs you probably should store them on disk instead of in the database.

Answer (score 0):

When you put the images into the same table that contains other song data, then all queries on the song data must also load some image data from the disk.

You can avoid this effect if you put the images into another table that has a 1:1 relationship with your main song table.
You can separate the image data even more if you put that table into a separate database that you [`ATTACH`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) to the main database; this even allows you to configure the caches differently.
This should have no speed difference to images stored on disk.

If you regularly need to export images to file (for editing or displaying in external programs), it might be easier to store the images in the file system in the first place.
Furthermore, having the images as files would make incremental backup easier (if that is a concern).